# Schroedinger equation in power law potential

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

Consider the one dimensional Schroedinger equation:
\begin{equation}
(1)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2 m} \frac{d^2}{d x^2} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 |x|^\mu \right) \Psi(x) = E \Psi(x)
\end{equation}
By introducing $\lambda := \sqrt{m \omega/\hbar}$ and by writing $E = (n+1/2) \hbar \omega$ we transform it to the following form:
\begin{equation}
(2) \left(\frac{d^2}{d x^2} + \left(\lambda^2 (2 n+1) - \lambda^4 |x|^\mu\right)\right) \Psi(x) = 0
\end{equation}
The question is now to find the quantum numbers $n = n(\mu)$ such that the solution is normalized, ie $||\Psi|| := \int\limits_{\mathcal{R}} \Psi(x) dx < \infty$. Of course in case of the harmonic potential $\mu = 2$ we have $n(\mu) = 0,1,2,\cdots$. The question is what is the result for $\mu \neq 2$?

I solved numericaly  equation (2) on a grid $\left\{ -10 + j \cdot 0.1\right\}$ for $j=0,\cdots,200$ using initial conditions $\Psi(-10) = 10^{-11}$ and $\Psi^{'}(-10)=0$. For each value of $\mu$ I recorded such value of $n(\mu)$ that minimised the sum of moduli of the wavefunction $\Psi$. Below you can see the functions $n(\mu)$ for the ground state and for the first two excited states.
[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the ground state quantum number does not seem to depend on the exponent $\mu$. If $\mu < 2$ then the spacings between the consecutive excited states seem to diminish with $n$, whereas if $\mu > 2$  the spacings between the consecutive excited states seem to increase with $n$.

Now, my question is is it possible to find a closed form solution for the function $n(\mu)$ for all excited states? What tools do functional analysis offer to tackle such problems?

Comment: Your initial conditions are quite strange. Why would you request that the wavefunction is nonzero at the boundary and has zero derivative? If you want to implement [shooting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method), you'd have to set wavefunction to zero and its derivative to nonzero at the first boundary and search for $n(\mu)$ which zeroes the function value at the second boundary.

Comment: [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/CI53ap3.png) how $n(\mu)$ looks according to my computations with $\lambda=10$.

Comment: @Ruslan: Thank you for this remark. In my calculations I used $\lambda=1$. I explicitely didn't seek to zero the value at the second boundary because if I start from either my old boundary conditions or, as you suggested $\Psi(-10) = 0$ and $\Psi^{'}(-10) = 10^{-11}$ then even in the case $\mu=2$ the wavefunction explodes at the other boundary. I was doing the calculations using NDSolve in Mathematica 8.0. Yet I will redo my calculations using the boundary conditions you suggested and see what happens.

Comment: If you use too coarse a grid or non-eigen value for $n$, it must explode indeed. But why do you have to use shooting method at all? Why not formulate an eigen-equation and solve it, automatically finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (which would approximate eigenfunctions)? It's much simpler than searching for root iterating `NDSolve` — you'd just use `Eigensystem` or `Eigenvalues` instead.

Comment: [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/p05GdHy.png) what I get for $\lambda=1$. Indeed, the values now increase with $\mu$. And here's [zeroth eigenvalue](http://i.imgur.com/Fek4m6N.png) magnified for comparison. (I computed with 381 points grid using discrete Fourier-like method (very similar to finite differences of infinite order) with `Eigensystem`.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in order to do what you are suggesting one needs to assume a certain basis in the Hilbert space. One can use the eigenvectors of the quantum harmonic potential for example. Since this basis is countable the problem reduces to diagonalising a infinite dimensional matrix. Of course that matrix needs to be truncated which will result in an error, just the same way I was getting my explosion errors due to using a too course grid. So maybe I am wrong but both approaches introduce numerical errors, errors that are hard to control.

Comment: One thing that bothers me is that your $n(\mu)$ diminish with $\mu$ whereas mine  increase. Is there another way of finding out weather $n(\mu)$ should increase or decrease?

Comment: Your wavefunctions are almost zero far enough under the potential. Thus you can cut off you configuration space and use $x\in[-10,10]$, for example. That's what I do. And using finite differences will trivially allow to compute then.

Comment: Mine decrease because I used $\lambda=10$. See a comment above with plots for $\lambda=1$.